# How to send focus lost event before mouse pressed event?

Tags: java, swing, focus, mouseevent, jtextfield

I have a simple GUI with two components: a `JTextField`, and a custom component (`MyComponent`).
Initially the text field has focus, and clicking on the custom component causes that to have focus.

Currently I am manually setting the focus using `requestFocusInWindow`, but the `focusLost` event happens after the `mousePressed` event has finished. Is there any way to get the `focusLost` event to happen before the `mousePressed` event finishes?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent event) {
                System.out.println("focusLost");
            }
        });
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.add(new MyComponent());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyComponent extends JComponent {
        public MyComponent() {
            setFocusable(true);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                    requestFocusInWindow();
                    System.out.println("mousePressed");
                }
            });
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because events are queued (all events called on the same thread) this is in the nature of AWT/Swing. Further events won't happen until the current method returns.

Comment: Right, but is there any way to get the focus to change before the `mousePressed` event?

Comment: @DanielGibbs, why do you need such option ? can you explain your use case, like do you want to validate your text field data before it loses it focus ?

Comment: Yea, but not for every keypress. It also needs to be validated (and stored) before the end of the `mousePressed` event, as the `mousePressed` event resets the text field with the value stored in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It also needs to be validated (and stored)

You can use an `InputVerifier` on the JTextField. It will validate the text in the text field before focus is transferred. If the data is not valid focus will stay on the text field.

Edit:

> Can I remove this behaviour and instead revert the text field to the previous value if the data is not valid when losing focus?

Instead of using a JTextField use a JFormattedTextField it will revert the data to the previous value. You don't need to use an InputVerifier. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: "If the data is not valid focus will stay on the text field." Can I remove this behaviour and instead revert the text field to the previous value if the data is not valid when losing focus?

Comment: Thanks, both `InputVerifier` and `JFormattedTextField` can do what I want.

Comment: That deserves a +1 just for deciphering the question